# Passing a 1xn array into a function handle instead of individual values for Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, handlers

I'm trying to find a way to pass a 1xn array into a function handler with n being the number of variables in the function so let's suppose I declare a handler as such:

```
U = @(x, y) x^2 + 2*y^2
```

and plugged in:

```
U(1, 2)
ans = 
     9
```

Is there some way I  can do something similar to this instead?

```
a = [1, 2]
U(a) 
ans =
     9
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can;

```
U = @(x, y) x^2 + 2*y^2;
a = {1, 2};
U(a{:})
```

When you expand the contents of a cell `{:}` it expands as the separate values stored in the cell. This is different from `myMatrix(...)` or `myCell(...)` which both produces a subset of the original set (be it a cell or a matrix).

Comment: The most common example of this usage is `varargin` which is of the type `cell`.

Comment: Nice! didnt know this! +1